# Восклицание "О(,) Господи!" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Речь о восклицании "О(,) Господи!" не в молитве, а, так сказать, всуе. По идее, тут обращение в Богу, но, с другой стороны, это уже своего рода устойчивое выражение. Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от контекста, точнее - от смысла.
При сильном эмоциональном акценте (обычно это относится к сочетаниям "о Господи" и "о Боже") "О" запятой не отделяется. Но это это не императивная рекомендация.

Что касается источника на грамоте: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_503, то его формулировки оставляют желать лучшего. Начнем с того, что совсем не очевидно, что "О" здесь междометие. Вполне можно трактовать и как усилительную частицу, следовательно, отсутствие запятой может быть просто частным случаем более общего правила о том, что частицы запятой не отделяются.

Answer (score 3):

> Междометие «о» не отделяется запятой от последующего слова в сочетаниях с обращениями, словами «да» и «нет», а также в сочетаниях «о господи», «о черт», если оно не выделяется интонационно.

[Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_503)

Comment: Согласен с behemothus-ом: "о" вовсе не междометие в этих сочетаниях, а частица.

Answer (score 0):

Так просто говорить нельзя, если Вы хотите употреблять это всуе.
"Не произноси имени Господа, Бога твоего, напрасно; ибо Господь не оставит без наказания того, кто произносит имя Его напрасно."
А как обращение к Богу, естественно, запятая нужна.

Comment: Оксана, правила пунктуации не оперируют понятием "всуе". Ответ надо аргументировать правилами русского языка, а не религиозными положениями (которые сами по себе безусловно заслуживают внимания).

Comment: Оксана права. И в своём ответе: в обращении, естественно, запятая нужна, и в том, что с обращениями такого уровня надо посерьёзнее быть. Тренироваться следует на кошках, а не на символах. Что до выражения, тем более устойчивого, — одно слово с междометием никак не может таковым быть.

Comment: Согласна с Бегемотусом. Если мы начнем еще и моралтные нормы тащить в правописание...

Comment: Ответ дан чёткий, согласно с Вопросом. А несогласие с аргументацией Ответа надо хоть чем-то подтверждать.

Comment: По-моему, **междометие "о"** с обращением встречаются редко, обычно частицы. Разве что такие: "О, Вася, да ты вырос-то как".